# Is it possible to partition $[a,b]$ into countably many "identical" sets which are translation from each other?

Tags: probability

Given $[0,1]$, is it possible to find one set $A_1\subset[0,1]$ and $A_i = A_1 + a_i, i\in\mathbb{N}, a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{A_i\}$ is a countable partition of $[0,1]$.

By $A_1 + a_i$, it means translating $A_1$ by the value of $a_i$, e.g. $[0, 0.5] + 0.25\triangleq [0.25, 0.75]$.

Edit: It turns out with constraint of modulo one, this $A_1$ could be the non-measurable Vitali set. And $[0,1] = \cup_{q\in Q\cap[0,1]}(V_1 + q)$.

Comment: I think you will find this question slightly more natural to ask about the circle. Or, equivalently, let your translation "loop around" modulo 1. At least I think it is so.

Comment: @Arthur I find the question in its current form fascinating, honestly; not being able to work mod 1 imposes a really interesting constraint.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Depends on what you want from this problem, I guess. I still find the circle more _natural_.

Comment: The problem is not clear.  When you translate, do you translate $\pmod 1$?  Something else?  But if you translate $\pmod 1$ then $0=1$ so if $A_1$ includes $0$ does it also include $1$?

Comment: @lulu Arthur, I was not thinking of modulo. But I doesn't hurt to have mod 1 for starter, in which case $[0,1]$ should be modified as $[0,1)$.

Comment: So then , the problem is standard.  Just look a the equivalence relation, $x\sim y\iff x-y\in \mathbb Q$  and use the Axiom of Choice to pick a representative of each equivalence class. Then $[0,1)$ is the union of all the rational translates $\pmod 1$ of this collection.

Comment: Thiis not possible if you want to partition the **closed** interval $[a, b]$ : in that case, $A_1$, must contain a maximum element $t$ that is mapped onto $b$ by translation through $b - t$, but then a left neighbourhood of $b$ will only contain countably many translates of $t$ and cannot be covered by countably many translates of $A_1$.

Comment: Your edit is not quite right: if you are working modulo $1$, then $1\bmod 1$ is $0$, so $1$ is not contained in any $A_i$. You mean $[0,1)$, not $[0,1]$.

Comment: PS: I think the original question was quite clear: if it wasn't what intended, then please edit it.

Comment: @RobArthan: I see why $A_1$ must contain a maximum element (although it is perhaps not immediately obvious). But I don't see why a left neighbourhood of $b$ will only contain countably many translates of $t$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TonyK - Each $A_i$ is a translate of $A_1$ and has in it only a single translate of $t$. There are only countably many $A_i$, so there are only countably many translates of $t$. But I admit that I don't see why this means only countably many translates of $A_1$ cannot cover a left neighborhood of $b$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I am having trouble understanding your final sentence. It seems to contain a double negative.

Comment: @TonyK - two negatives do not constitute a double negative when they negate different things. Rob Arthan uses the countability of the translates of $t$ to conclude that a left neighborhood of $b$ cannot be covered by countably many translates of $A_1$. I am admitting that although I see why there are only countably many translates of $t$, I do not understand why countably many translates of $A_1$ cannot cover a left neighborhood of $b$. I too am probably missing something.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Apologies if my comments have held up progress on this. I had doubts about my claim too, but hadn't had time to check my ideas properly until today. The line of proof I had in mind definitely does not work. In the opposite direction, I have tried to adapt Vitali's construction of a non-measurable set, but the lack of a group structure when translations are restricted to $[0, 1]$ makes that look difficult. I'd be interested to know the answer.